# multiple commands in the same bat file on windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, task, scheduled-tasks

```
cd c:\dspace\bin


dspace generate-sitemaps,
dspace oai import,
dspace index-discovery,
dspace index-authority,
dspace stats-util -o,
dspace filter-media,
dspace curate -q admin_ui,
dspace checker -l -p,
dspace checker -d 1h -p,
dspace checker-emailers,
dspace cleanup,
dspace stats-util -s
```

how do I run all these commands in the same file, I tried this way more, so the script runs the first. what is the right way to run them?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably the `dspace` is bat file.Try with:

```
cd c:\dspace\bin


call dspace generate-sitemaps
call dspace oai import
call dspace index-discovery
call dspace index-authority
call dspace stats-util -o
call dspace filter-media
call dspace curate -q admin_ui
call dspace checker -l -p
call dspace checker -d 1h -p
call dspace checker-emailers
call dspace cleanup
call dspace stats-util -s
```

Comment: If relevant, additionally I would suggest checking the return code for errors and error handling.